# Is it possible to see only the pictures I've taken on my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, photos, ios

I'm using an iPhone 5S, running iOS version 10.3.1.

I'm part of a chat group where a lot of pictures are posted. From time to time I want to see only the pictures I've taken in my photo app, but I can't find a way to do it.

When I open the Photos app, this is what I see in the different categories:

- Photos: All photos ever stored on my phone
- Memories: Some random photos the app chose for me
- Shared: Photos I've actively shared to others
- Albums: some different albums (e.g. Camera Roll, My Photo Stream, Selfies and Favourites. However, they either

  - include all photos on the phone (Camera Roll)
  - include the latest 1000 photos on the phone (My Photo Stream)
  - include pictures marked by me (Favourites)
  - include pictures marked by the phone as a certain type (Selfies)

There is even a section under Albums for the particular chat app I'm using.

Is there any way I can filter out the pictures from the chat group, and only see the pictures taken by this phone?

I've searched online for e.g. "iphone see only pictures taken by this phone", but the search only returns results such as "how to find out where you took photos".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a [workflow](https://workflow.is/workflows/9de5bbc05ae843998cc1d3e14fb98eb6) that filters all your photos from your camera roll. It gets all your photos, excluding an album(select album your chat photos are stored) and also screenshots(you can disable it if you want).

The workflow will ask you if you want to save it all in a new album or in an existing one. You will need to run it each time to update the album.

You will need the [Workflow app](https://workflow.is/) to run this.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this looks good! I'll wait a few days with accepting to see if there's a way to do this without an external app.

Comment: You can also do this with a mac(smart folders)

Comment: Does it need to have macOS? I only  have access to a Windows computer atm.

Comment: @HenricF Sorry, I don't know a way of doing that with Windows unless you could somehow sort photos by camera type

Comment: the workflow you link to does not work on ios 12 and the new shortcuts app. I get "The operation couldn't be completed. (cocoa error -1.)"

Answer (score 2):

So, it definitely depends on the app you are using. However, embedded geolocation metadata isn't typically kept when exporting or importing shared shared photos (for privacy). So, if you do a search with a broad location as the term — say, "United States" — this will only select images that have this metadata, which typically will be the only photos taken on your phone (though it will also include those synced with iCloud from another phone, screen grabs, etc.). See if that gets you what you want?

Comment: that looks like it works, thanks! I can use that together with the shortcuts app to make an album that just has pictures I took.